# media player pause is not working

Tags: android, media-player

On click of a linear layout I need to pause my streaming in the mediaplayer which is associated with a surface view.
But the player is not pausing.(I'm testing in emulator).
here is the code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(onBlooey);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        surface = (TappableSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        surface.addTapListener(onTap);
        holder = surface.getHolder();

        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        topPanel = findViewById(R.id.top_panel);
        bottomPanel = findViewById(R.id.bottom_panel);

        timeline = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.timeline);
        timeline.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (player != null) {
                    if (player.isPlaying()) {
                        player.seekTo(progress);
                    } else {
                        player.start();
                        player.seekTo(progress);
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        media = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.media);
        media.setOnClickListener(onMedia);

        seekbarTopPanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.seekbarTopPanel);

        playVideo();
        clearPanels(true);
        seekbarTopPanel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                topPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (player != null) {
                    System.out.println("in player pause");
                    player.pause();
                }

            }
        });
    }



public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        player.setDisplay(holder);
    }

private void playVideo() {
        try {
            media.setEnabled(false);

            if (player == null) {
                System.out.println("media player created");
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            } else {
                player.stop();
                player.reset();
            }
            // url="C:\\Users\\Sai Dinakar\\Downloads\\Relaxing Music & Beautiful Nature 6 1080p HD.mp3";
            Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                    + R.raw.nature);
            // player.setDataSource(url);
            player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), url);

            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.prepareAsync();
            // player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            VideoTimerHandler videoTimerHandler = new VideoTimerHandler();
            videoTimerHandler.playVideoTimer();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in media prep", t);

        }
    }
```

The issue is in oncreate -->seekbarTopPanel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

The on pause is getting called but still the video is not pausing.

Comment: Is the video 'pausable'? Have you tried verifying it with 'canPause()' ?

Comment: @avimak how do I do that--canpause?

Comment: VideoView.canPause() (only after your content is prepared)

Comment: @avimak this is not a videoview but it is a media player on a surfaceview

Comment: You must insure your content is 'pausable', otherwise calling pause() will have no effect.
VideoView does it for you by asking for Metadata (private API) once your content is prepared, which tells it whether the content can be paused or not. 
By not using VideoView, you will need to find it out yourself (there are many ways to achieve it, and the best one depends on the platform you are running on, whether the content is streamed or not, etc.)